# Invalid GUI request calling pylab with Ipython

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, ipython

I'm having a problem when calling `ipython --pylab` on ubuntu 15.04,
and I keep getting this error:

> [TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | GUI event loop or pylab initialization failed
>   UsageError: Invalid GUI request 'qt5', valid ones are:['osx', 'qt4', 'glut', 'gtk3', 'pyglet', 'wx', 'none', 'qt', 'gtk', 'tk', None]

I can't get it straight, does someone know how to fix it by any chance?

Comment: what version of matplotlib and ipython do you have installed?

Comment: ipython  - 2.3.0 and matplotib 1.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the desired backend as a commandline option.
e.g.:

```
ipython --pylab=qt4
```

Or any other in the list you got in the error message.

You could also specify the desired backend in your matplotlibrc file as
described here: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/customizing.html